# Is there a way to use onclick without really onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having this code:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;" class="submitme">Add</a>
```

is there any way to make an alert whenever the user will press this button without changing the code or adding onclick event?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question... for an alert to appear, an event has to happen in the first place. Can you give more information about exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I can't change any of the above html code, can't add any event on the code I've given above but I have to make whenever the user presses this "add" it will show him an alert, I've tried everything I knew without any success..any way to make it work?

Comment: What **do** you have the ability to change?  Do you have access to jquery?

Comment: I didn't say "ajax", I said "jquery"... two totally different things.

Comment: Onmouseup will do the trick. Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sxL5f/

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's the same, No I must not use jquery, only ajax\javascript..

Comment: I can't edit the html, so I can't add "onmouseup" event.

Comment: But you can use javascript to handle the onclick / onmouseup event.

Use Nikos code or check this other fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sxL5f/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP states that they are not allowed to change the HTML, and that jquery is not available to them.

Not having an 'id' on the link makes life very difficult. So the following code presumes the link is the very first one on the page...

Place this javascript into the `<head></head>` section of your page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = function() {
      alert("Hello World");
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

See [Live JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yd5La/)

Comment: You're welcome @Jonny - I would recommend that you investigate the technical difference between "ajax" and "jquery".  (jquery is a javascript library that allows for great cross-browser scripting... ajax is the method of passing information between the browser and server in the background.  The ability to do ajax is **included** in jquery, but that does not make them the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can simple overwrite the attribute with JavaScript:

```
// Select the targeted element(s), in this case the first <a> element
// Note: You will need to replace this by a code that works
//       for your actual markup!
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = function() {
    alert("hi");
    return false;
}​​​;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WNZAP/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to trigger an action without an event. But if I get your question right you want to trigger an alert without changing the HTML.

The easiest way would be by using a JavaScript library like jQuery. So load the library either by downloading it and placing it in your project or through the Google CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submitme").click(function(){
        alert("hello world");
    });
});
</script>
```